# JSONObject not being parsed by server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, retrofit

I am building an API, and when I send a request like this:

`POST http://myserver.dev`

```
{
"id": "1",
"string1": "hello",
"string2": "world"
}
```

everything works as expected testing this with `curl` and Postman. However, using my Android code, the request fails:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("id", "1");
        jsonObject.put("string1", "hello");
        jsonObject.put("string2", "world");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
```

And the server gives me this error:

```
JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '"{\"id\":\"1\",\"string1\":\"hello\",\"string2\":\"world\"}"'):
```

It seems as though this jsonObject is not giving me the expected json string. Any ideas what's going on here?

The full HTTP request from logcat is here:

```
04-26 15:23:56.468  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP POST http://api.s.com/games
04-26 15:23:56.469  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ X-Authorization: 10155399143045080
04-26 15:23:56.469  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
04-26 15:23:56.469  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 95
04-26 15:23:56.469  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ {"nameValuePairs":{"id":"1","string1":"hello","string2":"world"}}
04-26 15:23:56.469  21013-21669/com.johncorser.s D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (95-byte body)
```

And from the server logs:

```
2015-04-26T19:26:39.371386+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"_json"=>"{\"id\":\"1\",\"string1\":\"hello\",\"string2\":\"world\"}", "game"=>{}}
JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '"{\"id\":\"1\",\"string1\":\"hello\",\"string2\":\"world\"}"'):
```

Comment: i can assure you, it's not server response, parsing at runtime failed

Comment: The `JSON::ParserError` line came directly from my servers logs.

Comment: can you post the exact request which is being sent to server by logging it into logcat.

Comment: see my edits for the logcat http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a consequence of how Retrofit serializes objects before post.

I ended up switching from using a `JSONObject` to a `HashMap<String, String>` and not calling any `.toString()` method, Retrofit took care of the rest.